# Validating simplifications analytically

Tags: symbolic, simplifying-expressions

I have a rather complex expression which I would like to simplify and check my work along the way (*Mathematica* does not simplify very basic things and it is frustrating me). In the following example, all I am doing is writing the square root in the numerator and the square root in the denominator under one radical and *Mathematica* will not tell me that they are the same thing. the first expression (on the top) is the original and I am subtracting my simplification which should give me zero but it does not. I end up having to plot the differences and the more changes I make to my simplification, the more the computer error propagates which makes that a poor solution for validation.

How do I go about having *Mathematica* validate these simplifications for me analytically?

```
-((2^(5/2 - 2*t)*(4 + 2*t)!*Subscript[a, 0]^(-3 - 2*t)*
    (Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^(4 + 2*t)*
    Sqrt[-((64^t*(5 + 2*t)!^2*Subscript[a, 0]^(12 + 8*t)*Subscript[a, 1]^(5 + 2*t))/
       ((4 + 2*t)!*(16^(2 + t)*(5 + 2*t)!^2*Subscript[a, 0]^(3 + 2*t)*
          Subscript[a, 1]^(5 + 2*t) - (2*(3 + t))!*(4 + 2*t)!*
          (Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^(8 + 4*t))))])/(5 + 2*t)!) + 
 (2^(5/2 - 2*t)*(4 + 2*t)!*Subscript[a, 0]^(-3 - 2*t)*
   (Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^(4 + 2*t)*
   Sqrt[-(64^t*(5 + 2*t)!^2*Subscript[a, 0]^(9 + 6*t)*Subscript[a, 1]^(5 + 2*t)*
       (Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^4)])/
  ((5 + 2*t)!*Sqrt[(4 + 2*t)!*Subscript[a, 0]^(-3 - 2*t)*
     (Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^4*
     (16^(2 + t)*(5 + 2*t)!^2*Subscript[a, 0]^(3 + 2*t)*Subscript[a, 1]^(5 + 2*t) - 
      (2*(3 + t))!*(4 + 2*t)!*(Subscript[a, 0] + Subscript[a, 1])^(8 + 4*t))])
```

[image: TraditionalForm of the expression.]

Comment: please post the code for the function in `InputForm` so the rest of us can try to help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  When you post here, please make sure that 1. you post copyable code 2. you come up with a clear *minimal* example (in this case: why doesn't `Sqrt[a/b] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b]` simplify to `True`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are assuming that

$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}
$$

This is not generally true.  Take for example $a=1$ and $b=-1$ for which this identity does not hold.

You need to give additional assumptions to `Simplify`, in this case that $b>0$.

```
Simplify[Sqrt[a/b] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b], b > 0]

(* ==> True *)
```

Comment: ahh, beat me to it: though you had a better example anyway :)

Comment: As an added note, `Reduce` is nice in this case for determining when a particular simplification is valid.

Comment: thank you, this solve some of my problems. now, how can i get it to evaluate the gamma function as factorial when i have non-negative, integer arguments? i have tried {l >= 0, l :in: Integers} and it does not help.

Comment: @Laurbert515 I am not aware of any way to do that (`FunctionExpand` converts the other way) except though an explicit replacement, `... ./ Gamma[z_] :> Factorial[z-1]`

Comment: no problems - thanks for the help!

Comment: FullSimplify[Gamma[n + 1], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0] though I don't think it is really worth all the typing...